# Long delay for SQL Step under Spring batch improved by RAM DB increasing

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

I have a SQL running for 8 hours in Spring Batch, while when executed manually, it do not take more than 1 hour.

After investigation with DBA we raise SGA PGA value from 2,2 to 32, 10 respecively, and surprisingly, the batch realize the SQL step in 1 hour.

I want to understand how it's working and PGA SGA value role in that situation. And from that understanding maybe to optimize the ressources use

As you can see, the code is really very simple:

```
JobConfiguration
   private Step StepThree() {
        return createTasklet("StepThree", MyRepository::StepThree);
    }
     
    @Bean
    public Job myJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(StepOne())
                .next(StepTwo())
                .next(StepThree())
                .listener(jobExecutionCheckListener)
                .build();
    }
            
   @Override
   public void StepThree() {
        String sql =
                "insert into myTableToCopy\n" +
                        "select *\n" +
                        "from myTable source\n" +
                        "where not exists(select 1\n" +
                        "                 from myTableToCopy target\n" +
                        "                 where target.Car_ID = 
      source.Car_ID\n")";
      jdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(sql);
    }
```

Application is using Hikari - driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.OracleDrive
Oracle : 12.1.0.2.0

Thanks

Comment: What did the investigation reveal? Pga and sga are responsible for huge amounts of things, it is not worth just guessing at exactly what they helped to improve - especially when we have no idea what was limiting your performance before.

Comment: Unfortunately, we only increase these values because we saw better performance on one DB having this SGA/PGA value, so we did without understanding the mechanism.
I suspect Hikari pooling requiring more ressources but i can't go further on that reasoning. I monitor the batch and SQL during these 8 hours, the hash join table showed 100% in one1.5hour, that mean SQL was well executed correctly, but for app it can only terminate the step after 7 hours. And log do not show anything in the application side; apart some statistics coming from HIKARI-POOL (min, max, mean connection)

Comment: Oracle is a very complicated beast, there are many mechanisms in play and the importance will vary greatly. There’s also a load of edge cases that you might have hit that you would only know if you knew how to look properly. I think at this point, unless you have AWR data (ie you’ve paid for licensing) you have to chalk it up to more memory = better and going forwards you should be setting up this particular system with that much memory. Going forwards, you could invest in training specifically for Oracle performance which should allow you to see what you should be doing when a problem appears

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting all the rows into `myTableToCopy` in a single sql insert statement which is a single transaction.  This will require the database to allocate alot of memory for potentially rolling back the transaction if required if the number of rows being inserted is high.  Since you're already using spring batch, it would use less database resources if you split that single insert statement up into batches.

To do that, you could have an ItemReader (eg. JdbcCursorItemReader) that uses this sql statement...

```
select * from myTable source where not exists(select 1 from myTableToCopy target where target.Car_ID = source.Car_ID
```

You would then have an ItemWriter that would insert a list of items into the `myTableToCopy` table and define the Step with a chunksize to control how many items you are inserting per transaction.  This way you have many transactions of a much smaller size for inserting the data into the `myTableToCopy` table which would use less resources on your database server.